# Laravel - Store multi fields in session

Tags: php, laravel

Currently this is storing only first_name in session. I need to store some other fields which are in the same database row like user_role and city. How can I do that ?

**DashboardContaroller.php**

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
    {
        $this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'first_name');
        Session::put('firstName', $request->get('first_name'));     
        return view('dashboard.index',$this->data);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<form action="" method="post">
{!! Form::select('first_name', $firstNames) !!}
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

**View**

```
<p>{{Session::get('firstName','default value')}}</p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store the data as array:

```
Session::put('user', ['first_name' => $request->get('first_name'), 'user_role' => Auth::user()->user_role, 'city' => Auth::user()->city]);
```

View:

```
<p>{{Session::get('user')['city']}}</p>
```

Comment: Hi. I am getting no error but printing the city name. It is null

Comment: NOT printing city name

Comment: I am in a dark forest as a beginner. Could I ask you to give me an example and open a path to find the way.

Comment: Yes these are column names and stored in DB

Comment: Yes I exactly access that way

Comment: Thank you very much @Miguel

Comment: I need to leave my desk now for a meeting. I will try it when I am back amd keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Miguel. I tried your update. `{{Session::get('user')['city']}}`this prints my data as I am logged in and this is my session. Not the selected user's data.

Comment: @Selim how do you get the user selected data?

Comment: in my question I can get selected user' first_name. I am trying to get the other objects of user which are in the same row of database table.

Comment: For that you have to be sure your first name is unique in table, and do. `$user = User::where('first_name', $request->get('first_name'))->get()`, and then do, `Session::put('user', ['first_name' => $request->get('first_name'), 'user_role' => $user->user_role, 'city' => $user->city])` . I guess the user is in the model User.php

Answer (score 2):

You can store the object of the user, for example

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{
    $this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'first_name');
    Session::put('userData', ['firstName' => $request->get('first_name'), 'id' => $request->get('id')]);     
    return view('dashboard.index',$this->data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As I am a beginner could you please inject it into my controller for me to understand the syntax

Comment: And how is the view ? I will try now.

Comment: like this : `{{Session::get('user')['firstName']}}`

Comment: Hi. Getting this error **syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'**

Comment: Ok no error anymore but it is not printing `{{Session::get('userData')['id']}}` in view

Comment: because there is no value in `$request->get('id')` i just put it as an example, you can set there what you need instead of the id

Comment: I see. How can I set it ? Just a small example please. I need to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go

**DashboardContaroller.php**

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{
    $this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'first_name');
    Session::put('user', $request->all());     
    return view('dashboard.index',$this->data);
}
```

In your View either iterate over the data like this:

```
@foreach (Session::get('user') as $user)
     {{$user}}
@endforeach
```

Or use specific keys like

```
{{Session::get('user')['first_name']}}
```

Comment: Hi @Sher I am getting **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** Any idea ?

Comment: dump Session::get('user') first in your view to check what's it holding

Comment: I updated the controller, it was just storing user = first_name from request. Now its storing the all the data submitted through the form and is storing it as array associated with 'user'

Comment: Alternatively you can add specific data like this:

   Session::put('user', [
                           'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
                           'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
                           'email' => $request->get('email'),
     ])

Comment: Hi @Sher using `Session::put('user', [ 'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'), 'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'), 'email' => $request->get('email'), ]);` and `{{Session::get('user')['first_name']}}` I can view the first_name. But using `{{Session::get('user')['last_name']}}` I can not view the last_name. How can I view others ?

Comment: Is there a last_name field in the form. Do you validate it whether its empty or not. It will be better if you can place a working code online or share it through gist. Because without having a look at the background of your problem, It will be hard to predict the cause of a problem. By looking at your code, the community can help you better